# Efficiency of crossover in genetic algorithms

Tags: optimization, genetics, genetic-algorithms

[This question is basically clone of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6791748/efficiency-of-crossover-in-genetic-algorithms) . I am reposting it here because in my opinion it is more appropriate site and because I didn't actually see answer itself.

**Quote from there:**

> I understand the reasoning behind it: crossover allows the strengths
>   of two individuals to be combined into one individual. But to me
>   that's like saying we can mate a scientist and a jaguar to get a smart
>   and fast hybrid.

**My part of the question:**

I think you will agree that the only thing that differs GA from classic searches (gradient-like or pseudo gradient searches with some combination with anti-local optimum perturbations like simulated annealing) is crossover operation.

So that is the reason of doing crossover for example on Knapsack problem (on which as I heard GA doing good job) or any other example of GA you like?

**Additional question:**

Also is there any theoretical approach which shows crossover efficiency?

**Note:** Question is seemed to be complex (not only for me as for newbie) please answer your best do not try give precisely write answer.

Comment: A Particle Swam Optimiser (PSO) can (i think) be expressed as a particularly specific GA crossover and mutation function (It is a real stretch of the definitions though).
PSO's have a proof of convergence (under certain constraints). If I recall correctly it is in a paper by Miller (but I could be getting confused).

Comment: Could you please unfold the abbreviations (I am not specialist)?

Comment: Done. PSO = Particle Swarm Optimiser.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_swarm_optimization

The "Cross-over" is to breed each particle with the Global Best particle (Storing the position as a "gene").
The "Mutation" is to move according to the motion rules, using both the local best and global best "genes", and mutating all individuals every step.

Comment: PSO reminds me random search, such case there you don't have gradient and have to simulate it.